# Bit position to bitmask conversion using MPASM directives

Tags: pic, assembly, firmware

I'm writing firmware for a PIC16F877A in assembler, and I want to set some constants at the top of my source code to indicate which port is used for what, so that if needed I can easily change all the i/o pins around by changing the constant values and recompiling.

Like this:

```
O_LEDS   EQU      PORTA
CONSTANT O_RED    = RA1
CONSTANT O_GREEN  = RA2
CONSTANT O_BLUE   = RA3
```

In my code, I need a bitmask to represent the ports I'm using. My question is, how can I write an expression using assembler directives to calculate the bitmask?

Using my example above:

```
O_RED = 1
O_GREEN = 2
O_BLUE = 3
```

and the bitmask I want is:

```
movlw b'00001110'
```

If there was a *to the power of* operator, I could do something like this:

```
movlw (2 ^ O_RED) | (2 ^ O_GREEN) | (2 ^ O_BLUE)
```

but `^` in MPASM is a Bitwise exclusive OR, not *to the power of*.

Can anyone think of another way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used MPASM before, but does this work?

```
movlw (1 << O_RED) | (1 << O_GREEN) | (1 << O_BLUE)
```

Shifting to the left doubles a number.

`1 << x` == 2<sup>x</sup>

Comment: ah yes!!! I can't believe I didn't see that myself. Thanks.